# Transform vector with repeating values into a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, boolean, sparse-matrix

I have a vector of n size, which I would like to transform into the Boolean matrix of nxm, where m is a number of unique values in that vector.

```
a = repmat(1:5:20,1,3)
a = 
    1 6 11 16 1 6 11 16 1 6 11 16
```

The result I would like to have is the matrix 12x4:

```
 1 0 0 0 
 0 1 0 0 
 0 0 1 0 
...
 0 0 0 1
```

Any ideas how to do that without for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
a = repmat(1:5:20,1,3);  
b = unique(a);   

bsxfun(@eq, a', b)
```

The result would be:

```
ans =

 1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Isn't that basically `[ eye(4); eye(4); eye(4) ]`?

Comment: No, it is not. The result just happens to be the same. Replace the second line of the code by `b = fliplr(unique(a));` and see that the result is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = repmat(1:5:20,1,3)
b=unique(a);
c = repmat(a',1,numel(b))== repmat(b,numel(a),1);
```

but in general a loop will be faster, repmat is to be avoided.
So, now with a loop:

```
a = repmat(1:5:20,1,3)
b=unique(a);
c=false(numel(a),numel(b));
for ii=1:numel(a)
    c(ii,:) = a(ii)==b;
end
```